# How does CSS order apply?

Tags: html, css, padding

Suppose I have an element with 2 classes that both apply `padding-left` to it:

```
<section class="pad1 pad2">
    ...
</section>
```

then in my .css file

```
.pad1 {
  padding-left: 60px;
}


.pad2 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

How will `padding-left` be applied?

What rules should I know in this kind of situations?

Comment: last added property (last lines in stylesheet) will be applied. others will be overwritten.
https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/

Comment: CSS Stands for Cascading Style Sheets, so the answer is in the name itself, Cascading means to flow down, so what happens is CSS is read from top to bottom, which means the last added property will be applied and the others will be overwritten

Answer (score 1):

I hope you understand.

```css
.pad1{
  padding-left:60px;
}
.pad2{
 padding-left:30px;
}
.pad3{
 padding-left:30px;
}
.pad4{
 padding-left:60px;
}
```

```html
<section class="pad1 pad2">
  Hi, This is css padding solution.
</section>
 <section class="pad3 pad4"> 
  Hi, This is css padding solution. 
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is all about CSS selection precedence rules. At first you should understand what is CSS precedence value for each selector.

We usually use as a CSS selector class, ID, tag name, inline etc. Each selector have own priority value, priority table like below:

- For each **tag** (a, div, p etc.) selector = 1,
- For each **class and pseudo-class** (.class1, .class1:active etc) selector = 10,
- For each **ID** (#id) selector = 100,
- For each **inline style** (`<div style="color:red"></div>`) selector = 1000,
- For each **!important** (`.class { color: red !important;`}) selector = Infinity.

Suppose right now you have a selector like following:

```
 #nav ul a { color: gray; } = 100 (#nav) + 1 (ul) + 1 (a) = 102
```

Now come on your point, you have 2 class selector `.pad1` and `.pad2` which each selector value is 10 means equal so which one will work? If selection priority if equal then most last one will work so `.pad2` will be work, because CSS parser read document top to bottom. But if selection priority is different then higher one will work in this case order dose not matter.

For better understand see here with more clear explanation: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

In this situation always last one CSS class will be on priority:

**If `.pad2` will be last one then it will be overwrite on previous class `.pad1` like below:-**

```css
.pad1 {
padding-left: 60px;
}


.pad2 {
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="pad1 pad2">
This is class section
</section>
```

**If `.pad1` will be last one then it will be overwrite on previous class `.pad2` like below:-**

```css
.pad2 {
padding-left: 30px;
}

.pad1 {
padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section class="pad1 pad2">
This is class section
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules are applied to objects in the page that match their selectors in the order they are encountered in the style sheet. However With *!important*, the property will now give priority to the latest important value.